# Code completion still acknowledges macro after undef

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I have a bunch of macros defined that only serve a purpose within a small area of a project.  I want to undefine them so that they don't pollute the global namespace, but Visual Studio still acknowledges their presence after #undef in other files.  IE:

```
//A.hpp

#define A_MACRO
```

...

```
//~A.hpp

#undef A_MACRO
```

...

```
//B.hpp

#include "A.hpp"

#include "~A.hpp"
```

...

```
//main.cpp

#include "B.hpp"

A_MACRO // <- code completion recognizes this despite it being undefined
        // and invalid
```

Do I just have to deal with this, or is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: It seems Code::Blocks properly erases it beyond #undef, so it has to be something within Visual Studio's settings.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding Intellisense's cache through `Project > Rescan Solution`?

Comment: @MaxTruxa Tried it, the macro still shows up even when I #define and #undef it within the same file.

Comment: Is `~A.hpp` a valid filename? maybe it would be worth trying with another filename like `notA.hpp`.

Comment: @NmdMystery Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: @SJuan76 Visual Studio seems to accept it, and changing the name doesn't get rid of the problem so I think it's valid.

Comment: @MaxTruxa 2013 (express) pre-update

Comment: I can confirm this behavior under VS 2013 Ultimate (regardless of the file name).

Comment: @MaxTruxa So is this a bug or just a lack of a feature?  I don't have any previous versions of VS to test with.

Comment: Please note that, if you think about it, this could be considered a feature. Multiple `#define`/`#undef` pairs of same macro name are not that uncommon and in those cases leaving it in code completion could potentialy be useful. Code highlighting of macro name correctly stops after `#undef` which could be a hint that leaving macro name in code completion was intentional decision, then again it could be a bug or oversight.

Comment: Since you can't compile the code, but Intellisense isn't complaining about it, I would classify this as a bug in Intellisense. The `#define`/`#undef` doesn't even have to be spread over multiple files. I will file a bug and post back here.

Comment: @user2802841 I don't think this is the case, since Intellisense is also showing the value the macro *was* defined to in the suggestion dropdown.

Comment: Report: [C/C++: #undef does not clear macro from Intellisense suggestions.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812175)

Answer (score 0):

Its a perfectly valid tag.

Consider that somewhere in your code you may want to add:

```
#ifdef A_MACRO
...
#endif
```

or even:

```
#ifndef A_MACRO
...
#endif
```

Wouldn't it suck if your Intellisense quit working?

The macro label is a valid label in both of these contexts. Whether the macro is currently defined or not.

Comment: A member of the VC++ team recently wrote a response corroborating this answer at the [connect.microsoft.com link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812175) provided by Max Truxa in the comments on the question.